# Unable to Extract MTOM/XOP Attachment in C#

Tags: c#, mime, format-conversion

I'm still unable to extract the MIME attachment. Please check below MIME message. which we received from the service.

```
--MIMEBoundary_199ca6b7114b9acca5deb2047d25d5841d4afb7f68281379
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.099ca6b7114b9acca5deb2047d25d5841d4afb7f68281379@apache.org>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header><StateHeader xmlns="http://www.statemef.com/StateGatewayService"><MessageID>12345201704200009962</MessageID><RelatesTo>12345201704200009962</RelatesTo><Action>GetNewAcks</Action><Timestamp>2017-02-11T01:54:51.676-05:00</Timestamp><TestIndicator>T</TestIndicator></StateHeader></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><GetNewAcksResponse xmlns="http://www.statemef.com/StateGatewayService"><MoreAvailable>true</MoreAvailable><AcknowledgementListAttachmentMTOM><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:299ca6b7114b9acca5deb2047d25d5841d4afb7f68281379@apache.org"></xop:Include></AcknowledgementListAttachmentMTOM></GetNewAcksResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
--MIMEBoundary_199ca6b7114b9acca5deb2047d25d5841d4afb7f68281379
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <299ca6b7114b9acca5deb2047d25d5841d4afb7f68281379@apache.org>
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Get the *complete* MIME stream, i.e. the `Content-Type` header that defines the `boundary` parameter to be `MIMEBoundary_199ca6b7114b9acca5deb2047d25d5841d4afb7f68281379`. Without that, you are SOL.

If you are using something like `HttpWebRequest`, proceed to Step 2.

Step 2: Follow the instructions in the MimeKit [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ParseWebRequestFormData):

**How would I parse multipart/form-data from an HTTP web request?**

Since classes like `HttpWebResponse` take care of parsing the HTTP headers (which includes the `Content-Type` header) and only offer a content stream to consume, MimeKit provides a way to deal with this using the following
two static methods on [MimeEntity](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MimeEntity.htm):

```
public static MimeEntity Load (ParserOptions options, ContentType contentType, Stream content, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken));

public static MimeEntity Load (ContentType contentType, Stream content, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken));
```

Here's how you might use these methods:

```
MimeEntity ParseMultipartFormData (HttpWebResponse response)
{
    var contentType = ContentType.Parse (response.ContentType);

    return MimeEntity.Load (contentType, response.GetResponseStream ());
}
```

Once you have the MimeEntity, you can cast it to a [Multipart](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_Multipart.htm) and enumerate the attachments within, saving the content to a stream like this:

```
int i = 1;
foreach (var attachment in multipart.OfType<MimePart> ()) {
    string fileName = string.Format ("attachment.{0}.dat", i++);
    using (var stream = File.Create (fileName))
        attachment.ContentObject.DecodeTo (stream);
}
```

Comment: I could not find the .Parse() method within MimeKit in the latest version ? (July 2017). Therefore i gave up, and used the .NET framework only, see my answer using XmlDictionaryReader.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been MimeEntity.Load()

Comment: Hi both just wanted to say thanks for posting this...was tearming my hair out until I found this!

Answer (score 0):

The question shows only the response Body. To parse it, you should prepend the response Header.

For example, it should look like:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0 
content-type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="MIMEBoundary_someuniqueID";start-info="text/xml"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET 
Content-Length:24371900


--MIMEBoundary_someuniqueID
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml" Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>

<soap:Envelope> 
    <someWrapperElt>
        <xop:Include href="cid:uri_of_content"></xop:Include>
    </someWrapperElt>
</soap:Envelope>
--MIMEBoundary_someuniqueID
Content-Type: application/octet-stream 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary 
Content-ID: <uri_of_content>

...start.b1n@ry-content-here-etc.fckZ8990832d...
--MIMEBoundary_someuniqueID--
```

Then convert the whole response into a MemoryStream object, and use XmlDictionaryReader to parse it.

```
XmlDictionaryReader mtomReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateMtomReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
```

That is, you can now extract desired values out of the mtomReader object, including the attachment.

Comment: Do you have some sample code showing how to go about extracting attachments from the mtomReader above? I'm able to create the reader but now I'm stuck trying to get to the attachments.

Comment: Should someone still be interested in a solution on how to extract a file from an XmlDictionaryReader, I have asked a question about it and it got answered. You should be able to figure it out by looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76072693/how-to-extract-a-file-out-of-an-mtom-reader-xmldictionaryreader/76073687#76073687

Answer (score 0):

You can take parser project in [Github](https://github.com/emrahm/SoapMimeCSharp) 
WebResponseDerializer component can parse multipart soap message

1) Copy xml message between soap body tag to [xml2charp](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) site and take deserilized object.

2) Take response stream and call like below.

```
 Byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes("..\\..\\Data\\ccc.xxx");
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(file);
        WebResponseDerializer<SIGetImageResponse> deserilizer = new WebResponseDerializer<SIGetImageResponse>(stream);
        SIGetImageResponse ddd = deserilizer.GetData();
        foreach (var item in ddd.ResponseData.AttachmentDescriptor.Attachment)
        {
            String contentId = "<<" + item.ImageData.Include.Href + ">>";
            contentId = contentId.Replace("%40", "@").Replace("cid:", "");
            item.ImageData.Include.XopData = deserilizer.GetAttachment(contentId);
        }
```